# React routing not working - using react-router-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-bootstrap

I've 2 pages and I want to route to 2nd page by clicking on a `Button`. Here is the code.
**App.js**

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import { NavigationBar } from './components/Navbar/NavBar';
import CarouselMain from './components/Carousel/Carousel';
import { WhySurveyChamp } from './components/whysurveychamp/whysurveychamp';
import { TryItOut } from './components/tryitout/tryitout';
import { Services } from './components/services/services';
import { OurCustomers } from './components/ourcustomers/ourcustomers';
import { Footer } from './components/footer/footer';

import { NewSurvey } from './components/NewSurvey/NewSurvey';

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar />
        <CarouselMain />
        <WhySurveyChamp />
        <TryItOut />
        <Services />
        <OurCustomers />
        <Footer />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/NewSurvey">
            <NewSurvey />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`NewSurvey` is the 2nd page which I want to access by clicking on a `Button` in `NavigationBar.js`.
**NavigationBar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { Nav, Navbar, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'

// import { NewSurvey } from '../NewSurvey/NewSurvey';


export const NavigationBar = () => (
    <Styles>
        <Navbar expand="lg">
            
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <LinkContainer to="/NewSurvey">
                    <Button variant="outline-success" className="loginButton">Login</Button>
                </LinkContainer>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar> 
        
  </Styles>
)
```

**NewSurvey.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { NavigationBarOne } from '../Navbar/NavBarOne';

const Styles = styled.div`
       
`;

export const NewSurvey = () => ( 
    <Styles>
        <NavigationBarOne />
    </Styles>
);
```

But this doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please remove all code that is not necessary to answer your question

Comment: Done, please check...